# Untracked dirs on commit with pygit2

Tags: python, git, libgit2, pygit2

I'm working on a non-bare repository with pygit2

```
index = repo.index
index.read()

# write in test/test.txt

index.add('test/test.txt')
treeid = index.write_tree()

repo.create_commit(
    'HEAD',
    author, committer,
    'test commit',
    treeid,
    [repo.head.oid]
)
```

This is successful, but when I perform a `git status`, I got this :

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    test/test.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   test/
```

And after a `git reset --hard`, everything is fixed.

Is there a way to update correctly the index with pygit ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're only writing out a tree from your in-memory index and leaving the on-disc index unmodified, so after the commit it is at the same state as it was before you did anything.

You need to write out the index (`index.write()`) if you want your changes to be stored on disc.